Taylor condition on the general formula for momentum commutator
My quantum homework asked me the following question:

Prove that for any $f(x)$ such that $f$ admits a Taylor expansion, the following is true:
$$[f(x), \hat{p}] = i\hbar\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}.$$

I always use test function when I calculate commutators otherwise I get confused so I did:
$$[f, \hat{p}]g = -i\hbar[f\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x}-\frac{\mathrm{d}(fg)}{\mathrm{d}x}] = -i\hbar[f\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x}-g\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}-f\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x}] = i\hbar\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}g \implies[f, \hat{p}] = i\hbar\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}.$$
My question here is why did the original question impose the fact that $f$ must admit a Taylor expansion? Is it just to impose that $\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}x$ exists? Or did I make a mistake somewhere in the solution by assuming something that wasn't true?

Related.

Yes, it is mainly a matter of existence of $f'$.

I suspect that the person who set the problem had a proof in mind where you  say that $f = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and then use the fact that $[x^n, p] = n x^{n-1}$.
